# Access to HiddenField value using jQuery and .NET Framework 4

Tags: jquery, .net, visual-studio-2010

I am stumped with access the value of some dynamically created controls that contain a image, label, and hidden field.

This is what I am doing:

```
HTML
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ReportIcon.ascx.cs" Inherits="ReportIcon" %>
<div class="report-icons" style="background:white; color:#014886; border-radius:5px 10px 5px 10px / 10px 5px 10px 5px; width:255px; position:relative; text-align:Left; visibility:visible; padding:5px; margin:5px; overflow: hidden">
    <asp:Image ID="PDFImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/pdfIcon.png"/> 
    <div style="position:absolute; left:64px; top:27px; max-width:196px; overflow: auto">              
        <asp:Label ID="ReportNameLabel" style="font-size:12pt; padding-left:15px" runat="server" Text="Report"></asp:Label>
        <br />            
        <asp:HiddenField ID="FilePathHiddenField" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>

Code Behind
public partial class ReportIcon : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string reportName { get; set; }
    public string filePath { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportNameLabel.Text = this.reportName;
        FilePathHiddenField.Value = this.filePath;
    }
}

JQuery
function setupMouseEvents() {
    $('.report-icons').hover(
        function () { $(this).css({ 'background': '#B8B8B8' }) },
        function () { $(this).css({'background': 'white' })}
    );

    $('.report-icons').click(
        function () {
            $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected");
            $(this).addClass("selected");
            alert($('#<%=FilePathHiddenField.ClientID%>').val());
        }
    );
};

function init() {
    setupMouseEvents();
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    init();
});
```

I think the problem is that I am my html is contained in a content place holder as I am usting a master page.

When I look at the HTML in the browser, the hidden fields have ids of:
ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportListView_ctl00_FilePathHiddenField
ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportListView_ctl01_FilePathHiddenField
ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportListView_ctl02_FilePathHiddenField
ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportListView_ctl03_FilePathHiddenField

Anyone know how to access the calue of these in jQuery?

Comment: any other suggestions? I am stuck in the water until I figure this out unfortunately.

it all has to do with these controls being dynamically created (1 or more can be created at a time), their IDs being assigned at runtime, and that they are contained in a content placeholder.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add # sign for id selector of jquery

```
 alert($('#' + '<%=FilePathHiddenField.ClientID%>').val());
```

or

```
 var id = '<%=FilePathHiddenField.ClientID%>';
 alert($('#' + id).val());
```

### For Asp.net 4.0

If you are using Asp.net 4.0 version than have look to this : [ASP.NET 4.0 Client ID Feature](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34151/ASP-NET-4-0-Client-ID-Feature)

**Control.ClientIDMode Property** -Gets or sets the algorithm that is used to generate the value of the ClientID property.

**AutoID** 
 The ClientID value is generated by concatenating the ID values of each parent naming container with the ID value of the control. In data-binding scenarios where multiple instances of a control are rendered, an incrementing value is inserted in front of the control's ID value. Each segment is separated by an underscore character (_). This algorithm was used in versions of ASP.NET earlier than ASP.NET 4.

**Static** 
 The ClientID value is set to the value of the ID property. If the control is a naming container, the control is used as the top of the hierarchy of naming containers for any controls that it contains.

**Predictable** 
 This algorithm is used for controls that are in data-bound controls. The ClientID value is generated by concatenating the ClientID value of the parent naming container with the ID value of the control. If the control is a data-bound control that generates multiple rows, the value of the data field specified in the ClientIDRowSuffix property is added at the end. For the GridView control, multiple data fields can be specified. If the ClientIDRowSuffix property is blank, a sequential number is added at the end instead of a data-field value. This number begins at zero and is incremented by 1 for each row. Each segment is separated by an underscore character (_).

**Inherit** 
 The control inherits the ClientIDMode setting of its NamingContainer control.

Comment: I did have an # in my jQuery :) As far the the ClientIDMode Property, I am confused on what to use. If it was just one control then Static would be appropriate. But these controls are dynamically created and the page could have 1 or 100. What would you recommend?